# Show message box with form entries on submitting the from in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have a form which takes multiple inputs from user. Now I wanna show the inputs in a confirmation dialog and submit the form if user clicks OK. CanI use jQuery here??

Comment: Yes, you can. If you want to show us the code for what you've tried so far and describe how it's not working for you then I'm sure someone, maybe me, will be happy to help you get your code working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can use jQuery here. =)

Dino Esposito wrote an [excellent article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd722809.aspx) on using jQuery UI in the context of ASP.NET MVC. One of things that he walks through is a dialog-based form.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. The way I would do it would be to bind to the form's submit event, and display a standard JavaScript confirmation box:

Non-specific example:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myform').bind('submit', function(e){
        if(confirm('Write your confirmation message here')){
            return true; //submit form
        }else{
            return false; //suppress submission
        }
    });
});
```

[Events/bind - jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind)

Comment: it could be better... it was a very quick example just to illustrate the point. The if...return true isn't strictly needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it on the button onclick event.

```
<p>
 <input type="submit" value="Approval of payment" 
   onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {return true;} else {return false;}" />
</p>
```

that work for me =)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some very simple example code:

```
$("#submitButtonId").click(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  if (confirm('Message containing values')) {

    $("#formId").submit();

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a blog post [here](http://nickstips.wordpress.com/2011/08/11/asp-net-mvc-ajax-dialog-form-using-jquery-ui/) that goes through how to do this using AJAX including making client side validation work.  I wrapped it all up in a custom HTML extension method to make it reusable.  Check it out.